# Tableau Server Connectivity Issue with SparkSQL Connector

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api, databricks

I have a Tableau Report which I have created on Tableau Desktop using Spark SQL Connector (Simba). I am using Databricks for Spark Execution Engine. The same report when I am trying to publish and view on Tableau Server, it is giving Driver/Access Issue (screenshot attached). I have admin access to Server though and server in running as well.

Do I need to install additional drivers on Server to get the same connected ? Apologies for my limited knowledge of Tableau Server.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaws6.png)

Comment: Is your server sitting behind a firewall that blocks access to your database server? Check that your server can connect to the database server.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions at https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/tableau.html  for connecting Databricks to Tableau?

Answer (score 0):

There are few experiences i want to share for the above problem :

1. Driver(Simba) needs to be installed on Tableau Server as well as Desktop.
2. Once you install the Driver on the server, re-publish the report on Server which needs databricks connection otherwise you will keep getting the same error. Tableau server only reflects/read the report published after necessary driver is present on server.
3. Version of your Tableau Desktop should be either same or lower then version at Tableau Server otherwise report won't be published stating version mismatch error.

Feel free to share your feedback/experience.